# How can I pass a prop to another compomenet in TypeScript whitout getting the error cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to pass a prop from an object I created.
The object looks like this:

```
export type DVTStepperType = {
    stepOne?: StepOneData
  };

  export type StepOneData = {
    id: number;
    number: number;
    project_title: string;
    DVT: Boolean;
    catalog: Boolean;
    start_date: Date | string;
    end_date: Date | string;
    TG_TE_number: number;
    budget: number;
    short_title: string;
    short_description: string;
    comment?: string;
    department: string;
    costs_ran_on: string;
    documentation: string[];
    report: string[];
    project_report_sending: string;
    status_id: number;
    client_location_id: number;
    overall_contact_person: string;
    representative: string;
    other_authorized_persons: string[];
  }
```

And here is my component where I am trying to pass it:

```
import { StepOneData, DVTStepperType } from '../customStepper/DVTStepperType';
import { classes } from '../styles';

type StepOneProps = {
  stepOne: StepOneData;
};

const StepOne: React.FC<StepOneProps> = ({ stepOne }) => {
  console.log("Hello", stepOne);

  return (
    <div space-between>
      <p>Project Title: {stepOne.short_title}</p>
      {/* Add other components that use `stepOne` */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default StepOne;
```

the problem is I always get cannot read properties of undefined when I am trying to use a field from the object I created.

Comment: Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  Right now this seems to be dependent on private code (`ServiceDescriptionHeader` and `classes`) and on untagged third-party libraries (react and mui); please remove such references unless your question actually depends on them.  If your question does depend on them, then please include the relevant definitions for the private code, and add tags for the libraries.

Comment: They are not dependent on them.  I deleted the service description header and classes is just for styling so anything should do. I just need to know how to pass the props

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know about material-ui/react so I'll bow out now; good luck!

Comment: I don't care about material Ui. You can Use anything I just want to know how I can pass the props correctly

Comment: Whether or not you care about it, the example imports `Grid` from material-ui and uses `React.FC`.  I don't know about these so I can't investigate easily enough to be helpful; perhaps someone with relevant expertise can chime in.  If you don't get engagement then you could consider [edit]ing the example to remove such dependencies, to widen the potential audience.

Comment: React.FC is short for functioncomponent and the grid is just a div. They don't effect the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256074/discussion-between-razvan-razvi-and-jcalz).

Comment: We seem to be failing to communicate properly. If you reference third-party libraries that don't affect the answer, then you should consider removing those references and replacing them with plain TypeScript.  Telling non-experts that they don't need to know about something but leaving the example dependent on that thing doesn't improve the situation, unfortunately.  At this point I'm just repeating myself so I will not respond to further comments.  If I see the code edited to not refer to react/mui then I'll look again.  Otherwise, I don't think there's anything left to discuss; good luck!

Comment: My apology. I edited the code to not include react/mui and just a simple div. Please take a look

Comment: It seems you never instantiated your attribute stepOne, something like: stepOne = new StepOne( );

Or have you done it in other place?


Edit: Actually I've noticed you defined it as a type, instead of class. I dont't know if you need to create an instance. But give it a try if you have not done it.

Comment: So you have identified that the variable stepOne is undefined.  There must be a problem with the parameter you are passing into the StepOne function.  You haven't shown any code for that, so there's not much that can be done here.

Comment: I have shown the code for the StepOne. There isnt any more code. The fields declared in DVTStepperType should be accesible to me in the StepOne component. but they are not

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if stepOne is not undefined before accessing its properties. You can use optional chaining operator: ?.

For example,

```
<p>Project Title: {stepOne?.short_title}</p>
```

You can prevent "stepOne is undefined" error happening.

Update: you can use conditional rendering.

```
<Grid sx={classes.input}>
    <p>Project Title: {stepOne?.short_title}</p>

    { !!stepOne &&
         /* Add other components that use `stepOne` */
    }
</Grid>
```

Comment: I did check it and it is undefined. And I don't know why,  I can't pass it asa prop